# Div over fixed header

Tags: html, css

How can I create a `div` that is ontop of the header, but will go away when scrolling down while the header will stay at the top.
This is how it should look:

[image: When not scrollig down]
[image: When scrolling down a little bit]
[image: When scrolling down more]
[image: When scrolling even more down]

Comment: Please take a look at your question again... And post code... And tag correctly!

Comment: do you use bootstrap and a cms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide clear description of your problem with your code.
Does your application supports bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)?

Do you want something like this ? I have the screenshot for the same.
http://plnkr.co/edit/gETDDsIiqZXpFa9YtmE5?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  /* Note: Try to remove the following lines to see the effect of CSS positioning */
  .affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .affix + .container-fluid {
      padding-top: 70px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:100px;">
  <h1>Wallpaper</h1>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
<div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Header</a>
    </div>

</nav>

<div class="container-fluid" style="height:1000px">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent condimentum, quam vitae congue finibus, mi nulla accumsan tortor, sed lacinia quam purus non eros. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
      Donec sapien est, aliquam et est vitae, iaculis varius orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam sed augue augue. Fusce ac felis non risus cursus iaculis id quis justo. Praesent in velit
      accumsan, tincidunt nisi non, finibus justo. Maecenas aliquam elit neque, et mollis erat accumsan at. Ut a mauris in erat accumsan facilisis.
    </p>
    <p>Aliquam fringilla semper elit ut convallis. Fusce bibendum ornare felis sit amet fermentum. Nunc quis auctor nibh. Proin viverra, sem vitae posuere semper, erat quam molestie leo, sit amet posuere mi nisl non nibh. Etiam auctor luctus diam ut interdum.
      Duis erat velit, ultrices in nibh id, molestie lacinia metus. Suspendisse quam est, ultrices ac mi eu, auctor vulputate diam. Vestibulum consequat enim vitae fringilla dapibus.</p>
    <p>Ut ut lobortis est, eu tempus justo. Morbi venenatis velit eget auctor fermentum. Ut auctor non mauris in tincidunt. Sed gravida mauris vel mattis aliquet. Vestibulum semper ipsum placerat, congue massa at, vehicula nibh. Pellentesque tincidunt, lorem
      at luctus gravida, diam turpis iaculis mauris, nec venenatis lacus odio vitae elit. Integer ullamcorper sagittis ipsum, ac aliquet mauris tempus at. Nam imperdiet, orci vel tincidunt semper, purus nibh bibendum risus, ac pretium felis dui sed justo.
      Nunc consectetur venenatis neque, sed sodales lacus egestas nec. Praesent convallis facilisis facilisis. Quisque eget dui faucibus, interdum dolor eu, imperdiet sem. Donec quis ante in dolor accumsan convallis. Donec vel justo ac mauris fermentum
      vulputate. Curabitur vel nibh quis nisi fermentum hendrerit vitae in ipsum. Sed consectetur purus tristique ante vulputate ultrices.</p>
    <p>Donec ut sapien nec massa cursus viverra ut at lectus. Pellentesque pellentesque, eros quis venenatis mollis, mi ligula aliquam arcu, sed hendrerit velit nulla efficitur massa. Phasellus laoreet risus nec dictum ultrices. Nam posuere porttitor condimentum.
      Donec accumsan elit et tortor blandit, a tristique erat porttitor. In quis tincidunt arcu, id semper ex. Suspendisse rutrum sed neque eget dapibus. Pellentesque a urna non urna accumsan feugiat a sed metus. Donec consequat luctus ullamcorper.</p>
    <p>Aenean viverra ipsum non lorem laoreet, id feugiat leo volutpat. Ut ex erat, cursus non ullamcorper sit amet, ullamcorper sed ante. Curabitur ultricies, magna ac accumsan dictum, odio felis mollis enim, et ultricies arcu justo vel nisi. Suspendisse
      potenti. Vivamus elit turpis, scelerisque vitae elit vitae, aliquet viverra purus. Phasellus finibus, mauris vel facilisis interdum, ante nisl ullamcorper felis, feugiat hendrerit arcu mi a est. In ut metus a ligula ultrices tincidunt. Praesent
      ullamcorper sem sapien, ac condimentum erat pellentesque a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rutrum est et massa venenatis interdum. Quisque convallis finibus lectus vitae semper. Vivamus pharetra lacus sed nulla blandit,
      sollicitudin semper velit auctor. Sed erat enim, aliquet at massa et, dignissim sodales lorem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras euismod ligula vitae sollicitudin posuere.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: When scroll is at top]
[image: When scroll is moved down]

Comment: @Arno Rohner please try and let me know.

Comment: You can go through this link http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp

Answer (score 0):

I wass fideling around with this fro a cuple of minutes and i think that i manged to get i working they way you want. This example is built on bootstrap, but shuld be able to aply it the most things. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linushg111/2w7vxy51/)

jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

CSS

```
nav.navbar{
  top:30px;
  background-color:#ccc;
   // Animation
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
   transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

nav.navbar.shrink {
top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the coomplet code if you need, just

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
       $('nav').addClass('shrink');
     } else {
       $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
     }
    });
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <style>
    nav.navbar{
     top:50px;
     background-color:#ccc;
      // Animation
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      transition: all 0.4s ease;
    }

    nav.navbar.shrink {
    top:0px;
    }

    </style>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <strong>Navigation bar</strong>
        </div>
    </nav><br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```